# How to define default control properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want every textbox I add to one of my forms to look the same and have the same properties. And I give textbox for example, I want this for buttons and comboboxes as well. my question is how to define a default set of properties for each control.
can i do it to the forms as well?

Comment: You can create custom controls which doesn't change anything but default values. E.g. `MyButton : Button` and in constructor override default values with yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom class of each control. For example, if you want textboxes that say "hello world", you would use this.

```
public class NewTextBox : TextBox
{
    //The constructor, called for every new instance of the class.
    public NewTextBox()
    {
        Text = "hello world";
    }
}
```

And then to use this in your form you call a new instance like so.

```
NewTextBox tb = new NewTextBox();//Create new text box
Controls.Add(tb);//Add text box to form.
```

Comment: ok thanks! another question, when using it in my form this way will I see it in the designer?

Comment: You will see it in the Control Toolbox in Visual Studio and you can drag drop onto forms and controls

Comment: Sometimes they don't automatically appear in the designer, when this happens, create an instance of the class in the form's constructor (public Form1()....etc.) and then run the program. Now you will see the control in the toolbox and you can remove the instance from the designer.

Comment: Could you press the tick please?#

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to create your own control library by inheriting from the base controls and decorate properties with the `DefaultValue` attribute. For example:

```
public class MyTextBox: TextBox
{
  public MyTextBox()
  {
    Text = "Hi";
  }

  [DefaultValue("Hi")]
  public new string Text 
  { 
    get
    {
       return base.Text;
    }
    set
    { 
       base.Text = value;
    }

}
```

The `new` keyword is used because the property is redefined.

Comment: This is a good idea for designer default values. You still need to set default value somewhere. E.g. in constructor `Text = "Hi";`.

Comment: @Sinatr: you are right, thanks, I've updated the answer.

Comment: +1 for providing the default value attribute. But shadowing the base `Text` property is not a good idea. Most of the properties are made virtual specifically for overriding and applying a different attributes. The correct answer would be `[DefaultValue("Hi")]public override string Text ...`.